# Automatically set Checkmarx configuration on project in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, checkmarx

Dear stackoverflow community;

I use : SonarQube 6.7.6 with Checkmarx plugin : 8.60.0

I need to configure my project in SonarQube with Checkmarx infos during security analysis so that in SonarQube analysis step, it can retrieve them and populate the project with all Checkmarx analysis data.

As explained on [Configuring a Project for the Checkmarx SonarQube Plugin](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/169345207/Configuring+a+Project+for+the+Checkmarx+SonarQube+Plugin).

I can do it manually but, it's better my pipeline does it automatically.
How can I set for example by Rest Api this project configs prior to SonarQube analysis (Server Url, Username, password, ...) or with some analyses properties so that they can be taken automatically.

I couldn't find the Rest Api on SonarQube to do that.

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks a lot.
Wognin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkmarx settings can be configured in SonarQube by making multiple post calls

POST `/api/settings/set?component=${sonarProjectKey}`

```
component=${sonarProjectKey}
key=checkmarx.server.credentials.secured
value={
  cxServerUrl: ${cxServerUrl},
  cxUsername: ${cxUser},
  cxPassword: ${cxPassword}
}
```

```
component=${sonarProjectKey}
key=checkmarx.server.project_name.secured
value=${projectName}
```

```
component=${sonarProjectKey}
key=checkmarx.server.remediation
value=${minutes}
```

To fetch corresponding key & value

GET `/api/settings/values?keys=checkmarx.server.remediation&component=${sonarProjectKey}`

Comment: Great !!! Thanks very much Sai. This is what I was expected. It works fine. Thanks again !!!

Comment: @sai anudeep, is this normal that the secured settings don't appear in the sonarqube ui? I only see the remidation property there